# Discord.js GuildOnly command

Tags: node.js, typescript, discord.js

How can i make a command guildOnly like this? https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/824411059443204127/925437730895306802/unknown.png

This is what my command handler looks like

```
import { Command } from './@types'
let commands: Map<string, any> = new Map()
let aliases: Map<string, any> = new Map()
const commandFolder = fs.readdirSync(path.resolve(__dirname, `./commands`))
for (const folder of commandFolder) {
  const commandFile = fs.readdirSync(path.resolve(__dirname, `./commands/${folder}`)).filter(file => file.endsWith('.ts'));
  for (const file of commandFile) {
    const cmd = require(`./commands/${folder}/${file}`) as Command;
    console.log(`${cmd.name} in ${folder}`);
    commands.set(cmd.name, cmd);
    if (!cmd.aliases) continue;
    if (cmd.aliases.length > 0) for (const alias of cmd.aliases) { console.log(`${alias} configed to ${cmd.name}`); aliases.set(alias, cmd); }
  }
}
```

Comment: You're using text based commands and not the newer slash commands right?

Comment: I also have a slash command handler
```
let slashes: Discord.Collection<string, any> = new Discord.Collection();

client.on('ready', () => {
  fs.readdirSync(`${__dirname}/slash-commands`).forEach((dir) => {
    fs.readdirSync(`${__dirname}/slash-commands/${dir}`).forEach(async (cmd) => {
      const file = await import(`${__dirname}/slash-commands/${dir}/${cmd}`);
      await client.guilds.cache.get("875064681079898122")?.commands.create(file)
      await client.application?.commands.create(file);

      slashes.set(file.name, file)
    })
  })
})
````

Comment: `if(cmd.guild && message.guild.id !== GUILD_ID) return;` if it's not with interactions.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If using `message` based commands based on the [`client#messaageCreate`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-messageCreate) event, the easy approach is to assert when `guildOnly` is set true, that there's [`message?.guild`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=guild) exists with:

```js
if (command.guildOnly && !message.guild) {
    return
}
```

---

When using slash commands you can directly register [guild slash commands](https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/application-commands#create-guild-application-command). Or when creating [global slash commands](https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/application-commands#create-global-application-command), you can set [`channel_types`](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#channel-object-channel-types) in the [options param](https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/application-commands#application-command-object-application-command-option-structure) that `channel_types` to only be shown in guilds